# Paypal gets the wrong amount value via the form

Tags: paypal

In below code I send via a variable different amounts to Paypal when using this form. All data is correct even the amount is correct when Element inspecting via browser. But when Paypal site is active I always get 1 amount value USD25.00. **It should be different for each $pitch->option_value.**

Each variable $pitch->option_value is correct filled at my site. But Paypal only sees 25.

> What do i do wrong or forget to do?

```
$i = '1';
foreach($pitches as $pitch) {
 if($i == 1) {
    $month =    __('Month','agent-plugin');
 } else {
    $month =    __('Months','agent-plugin');
 }

$content  .= '<form id="GotoPaypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="'.get_home_url().'/en/my-account/">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$i.' '.$month.'">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$pitch->option_value.'">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<a href="#!" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById(\'GotoPaypal\').submit();"> 
</form>';
    $i++;
}
return $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the value for $month will always be the same, no matter what value $i will have...

```
if($i == 1) { $month="25" } else { $month="25" }
```

will do the same trick ;)

You definded $i as somekind static value, why?

Comment: where do you increment $i? Foreach will not increment it by itself, use for($i=0;$i<$pitches_count;$i++)

of course: $pitches_count=count($pitches);

Comment: $i I need this as additional info for the payment.
$month is text in this example not an amount.
The amount is presented with $pitch->option_value. So the option_value is getting from a table.

Comment: you can also use foreach, but before the end bracket of foreach increment the $i value by adding $i++; statement

Comment: Sorry I forget to add $i++; in my example. Just added it.